# assigning IS NULL to a string before querying DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an excel spreadsheet with 15 or so fields. Wat I'm doing is, i open it, grab a row of data, then check each row for a value. Then using a few criteria I go look up to see if this Client value is already in the DB. As Example

Some of the fields mind be empty. Basically after checking some of the fields, I use them to check if that record exists already in DB. the problem arises when some fields are empty in which case when I query sql server it looks something like...

```
Select * from TblA where Company='Apple' and CompanyAdd ='Cupertino' and City=''
```

Because City = '' - it doesnt not find anything in SQL. The only thing that works is

```
and City is NULL
```

How am I able to programmatically assign that to a variable like CITY?

it is a string and the field in SQL is varchar

EDIT:

I want to be able to do something like this..... (as example)

```
if city = "" then
   'I need this here to be so that....
   city IS NULL
End if
```

So that when I query db it looks something like...

```
Select count(*) from TblA where City is Null
```

Is somethng like that possible?

Comment: `...AND City IS NULL` if the column allows empty strings `AND (City Is NULL Or City ='')`

Comment: @plutonix see my edit

Comment: `Is Null` is SQL not VB so the IF block wont work.  Whats the problem with 2 WHERE conditions in the SQL if that is what you need?

Comment: @plutonix - Well that's an alternative. We have a bunch of more code where this field is being used in WHERE statement. I just did not anticipate this field to be empty - it just so happens that out of 17000 thousand records there are 2 where this field is empty. Now I'm afraid I'll need to check every single field (this is getting extracted from xcel spreadsheet)

Comment: Well, you could run a query to update City (or SSN) to `'' WHERE City` (or SSN) `Is Null` before you start processing so that the data is fixed to be like what the query expects

Comment: @plutonix - i was hoping there would be a way to do something with .Replace or something. Something along the lines if city="" then city.replace("",'isNull') I dont know. Thanks for your help i might just have to shorten the number of conditions

Comment: How is `Update brokenTable SET City = '' WHERE City Is Null` a chore?  It fixes all rows all at once so there are no more nulls anywhere and prevents you from having to make other changes elsewhere.

Comment: @plutonix - i guess that would work. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) for this purpose.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblA 
WHERE COALESCE(Company, '')='Apple' 
  AND COALESCE(CompanyAdd, '') = 'Cupertino' 
  AND COALESCE(City, '') = ''
```

Keep in mind that the performance of this query will most likely not be stellar.